# Angular.js wait for multiple resource (ajax) calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have an Angular.js application and I need to call three different resources and once they all complete, use them together. My three calls are below.

```
# Get the curriculum
$scope.curriculum = CurriculumResource.get id: $routeParams.id

# Get the list of courses
$scope.courses = CourseResource.query()

# Get the list of groups
$scope.groups = GroupResource.query()
```

How can I perform more logic once I know the requests are all completed. I've tried using $watchGroup shown below and $watchCollection but neither seem to be working.

```
$scope.$watchGroup ['curriculum', 'courses', 'groups'], ->
    # Shouldn't this run each time something in the above array changes?
    console.log 'Only runs once'

    # The values of the items in the below if statement eventually give a true result
    # but the if statement never runs when they are true
    if $scope.curriculum.groups and $scope.groups.length          
      console.log 'never gets here!'
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could accomplish this with [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) assuming all of your requests return promises. Something like

```
$q.all([CurriculumResource.get({id: $routeParams.id}), CourseResource.query(), GroupResource.query()])
  .then(function(results){
     // results will be an array of values from resolved promises in the original order
   })
   .catch(function(err) {
     // will fail on any rejected promise
   });
```

Comment: I am using this and the Courses and Groups return fine but the Curriculum results (results[0]) is still an unresolved response. I am not sure why. The form on the page that this controller is on displays the curriculum data fine so the promise does get resolved. I am just using the $resource module with default settings. The only thing really set in my CurriculumResource is the url.

Answer (score 1):

Inject $q service, and use it this way:

```
$q.all(
  [
  CourseResource.query(),
  CurriculumResource.query(),
  GroupResource.query()
  ]
).then(function(response) {
  $scope.courses = response[0];
  $scope.curriculum = response[1];
  $scope.groups = response[2];
  // do what you need to do when all data is available
});
```

Also, you need to make sure your services are returning $q deferreds, all request returned by $http are deferred so you can return them, but maybe you want to wrap it to process the results (for example to extract the important info, o to preprocess data with model logic):

```
...
query: function() {
  return $http.get("...url...").then(function(response) {
    //process response here before return it
  }); // of course, the use of .then is optional
}
...
```